# How to Write a Bullying Scene?

Tags: characters, book, scene, cliches

In my newest story, the protagonist gets bullied constantly, and I'm planning for him to be driven to suicide later on the the story. But, I'm completely stuck on how to write a realistic scene, which fosters feelings of horror throughout. I want it to be violent, and almost too disturbing to read. It's going to be written in 3rd person, so I want to also get into the bully's head, show why he's bullying the protagonist and what he gets out of the way he treats him. I want to avoid typical cliches that some aspiring writers display, such as having the bully only torment the protagonist because they get a thrill out of it or just because they're malicious. But, my story is filled with those cliches.

Any tips or examples?

Comment: Do you want violence?  Exclusion?  Taunting?  Do you need to get into the bully's head, or are you okay with the bully being a black box?  Do you want to describe the bully (physically, psychologically) -- I would lean toward not.  Do you want a cold, clinical description?  Have you figured out how you're going to make believable the lack of protection from others that permits so much repetition?  What do you mean by "horrible"?  Are you after blood and gore, or what?

Comment: Wow, I redid the English in the question and then someone else's name appears. Whassup with that?

Comment: Hey, this question is unfortunately very broad for us. Can you narrow down what, precisely, you're having trouble with? What is it about your attempts that leaves you stuck, or feeling unsuccessful? Comment, or edit the question, and if we can get this into answerable scope, we'll be happy to reopen :)

Comment: I don't have enough rep to vote to reopen.  Your edit was helpful.  In general I have a hard time reading about violence, but I did manage, once, to read a couple of chapters of a book by Carlos Martínez Moreno about physical torture.  https://www.amazon.com/El-Infierno-Carlos-Martinez-Moreno/dp/0930523482 It was chilling, devastating, really.  Maybe reading that book would help you write effectively about one human being perpetrating unspeakable things on another.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend watching 'A Girl like Her' which is a documentary style film about some vicious bullying.

That might give you some ideas for the actual content of the scenes.

Writing wise, it's the same as writing anything else really: show, don't tell, describe physical details, be specific rather than vague. Give moment by moment description of important parts, don't summarise.

You could follow the Motivation > Reaction sequence as well, which goes like this:

Motivation:
Sally grabbed Ambrose's tie and yanked it downwards. (an external action)
Reaction:
Ambrose's neck felt like it was going to snap (feeling), he staggered forward a few steps to avoid falling (reflex), then glared at Sally.
"Let go," he pleaded. (rational action and speech).

You can read more about that here: http://www.advancedfictionwriting.com/articles/writing-the-perfect-scene/
Or here: http://www.helpingwritersbecomeauthors.com/motivation-reaction-units

I might add that the topic you want to write about - bullying and suicide - is quite a sensitive one, and if you haven't experienced bullying yourself, you should approach it with care.

Comment: While I agree wholeheartedly with this answer, I'd further suggest reading what people that suffered (and/or suffer) bullying went (go) through. It can go from mild discomforting situations to despairing, harrowing situations. It will help you get in the character's skin while at the same time see how cruelly diverse bullying can be. However, do not copy the exact situations you eventually hear about. Use them as starting points.